# Retrieving query metadata from within Neo4jclient

Tags: neo4jclient

Is there a way to retrieve the query metadata within Neo4jClient which can be returned after executing a Cypher querty.

Within the Neo4j browser when making a request against the server the following kind of response is returned.

```
{
  "results":[
    {
     "columns":[

     ],
     "data":[

     ],
     "stats":{
        "contains_updates":false,
        "nodes_created":0,
        "nodes_deleted":0,
        "properties_set":0,
        "relationships_created":0,
        "relationship_deleted":0,
        "labels_added":0,
        "labels_removed":0,
        "indexes_added":0,
        "indexes_removed":0,
        "constraints_added":0,
        "constraints_removed":0
        }
      }
    ],
    "errors":[

    ]
}
```

The block I am interested in is the stats block.

A quick look at the request shows a *includeStats=true* flag being set but I see no inclusion of it within the neo4jclient code.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time, no.

There are some stats on the `IGraphClient.OperationCompleted` event, but not these ones.

You are welcome to extend this event and send a pull request at https://github.com/readify/Neo4jClient/